# In MySQL replication, why aren't queries run on the slave when there was no USE statement on master?

Tags: mysql, replication

We have replication running from our master server to a slave. `binlog_format` is the default; `mixed`.

We have noticed something weird and are not sure whether it's a bug or intended behaviour. Certain statements are being ignored.

### Ignored

```
DELETE FROM schema_name.table_name WHERE id = 123;
```

### Works

```
USE schema_name;
DELETE FROM schema_name.table_name WHERE id = 123;
```

### Also works!

```
USE different_schema_name;
DELETE FROM schema_name.table_name WHERE id = 123;
```

When I delete something without previously selecting a database on master, the query is ignored on the slave. But when I issue a `USE schema_name` on the master before the statement, *even if it is a different schema*, then it does run on the slave.

Regardless of the `USE` and whether they run on the slave, they always appear in the binary logs on master.

We noticed this as we have a script that tidies up old shopping carts that loops over a list of databases and issues `DELETE FROM schema_name.carts WHERE created_at ...`, but replication was breaking when an `INSERT INTO carts SET cart_number = 'xxx'` call took place on the slave; the cart number (unique column) no longer existed on master (after a successful check to validate such) but on the slave it still existed so it threw the error and broke replication.

**Is this intended behaviour? What's the best method to ensure this kind of behaviour doesn't happen?**

For reference and possibly meaningful, master is MariaDB (in a drbd cluster) and slave is Percona.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide the relevant `my.cnf` entries.

If you have

```
binlog_do_db = B
-- Note:  That implies ignoring other dbs
```

and you do

```
USE A;  -- either explicitly, or due to the connection parameters
UPDATE B.tbl ...;
```

That `UPDATE` will be ignored.

Comment: In our case both tables in question are replicated, and not ignored. Your example seems to be the opposite way round - when we have `USE`, even a different schema, it works. But without, even when specifying the schema in-line, it doesn’t. I’ll post relevant config tomorrow when I can get on the server though for a closer look.

Comment: @LeonardChallis - You are right; my example was backward.